# Unable to build native android jar file

Tags: android, nativescript

- I have referred this [Creating native android packages and using them
  in nativesript](https://www.nativescript.org/blog/plugins-and-jars).
- I'm creating one android native jar file and I'll use it in
  nativescript.
- So I followed that tutorial. Finally I'm unable to build a jar file.
  release folder also not been created in my local project folder.

**build.gradle :**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 25

    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}



// task to delete the old jar
task deleteOldJar(type: Delete) {
    delete 'release/ToastPlugin.jar'
}

// task to export contents as jar
task exportJar(type: Copy) {
    from('build/intermediates/bundles/release/')
    into('release/')
    include('classes.jar')
    // name the plugin
    rename('classes.jar','ToastPlugin.jar')
}

exportJar.dependsOn(deleteOldJar, build)
```

**Toaster.java:**

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Toaster {
    public void show(Context context) {
        CharSequence text = "Hello NativeScript!";
        int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;

        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
        toast.show();
    }
}
```

**manifest.java:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.buildpack">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Below I have posted last line screenshot which has been generated when I'm clicked on export jar in gradle. I haven't seen build jar successful message till now.

[image]

Comment: The blog post looks a bit outdated - published almost a year and a half ago, when Android Studio itself was in its youth. Please follow the official Android documentation when looking to build android plugins with gradle/android studio.

Answer (score 0):

Android libraries which use the `apply plugin: 'com.android.library'` plugin in their gradle script will output `.aars`

Refer to https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/android-library.html for complete instructions on building your `aar`. You'd like to call the `assemble`, or `assembleRelease` task to get the aar library in your plugin outputs.